# Solutions of $x^d=1$ in the symmetric group

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

L Moser and M Wyman, *On solutions of $x^d = 1$ in symmetric groups*, Canad. J. Math., 7 (1955), pages 159-168, explored asymptotic behavior of the cardinality of such permutations:
$$f_d(n):=\#\{\pi\in\mathfrak{S}_n:\, \pi^d=1\}.$$
In particular, $f_2(n)$ counts the number of *involutions* in the symmetric group $\mathfrak{S}_n$.

> **Question 1.** I recall (but forgot where) $f_d(n)$ enumerate *pseudoknots* in RNA molecular folding. Can you explain this or point me to a readable reference?

Also,

> **Question 2.** Does this generating function hold true?
>   $$\sum_{n\geq0}f_d(n)\frac{x^n}{n!}=e^{\sum_{c\,\vert\,d}\frac1cx^c}.$$

Comment: Question 2 is true by a standard application of the exponential formula. See for instance *Enumerative Combinatorics*, vol. 2, equation (5.31).

Comment: I bet that you'll be interested in the paper *"p-Divisibility of the Number of Solutions of x^p = 1 in a Symmetric Group, Annals of Combinatorics 5 (2001) 197-210"*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Q2. Of course, this is a general thing for exponential generating functions. Assume that $a(n)$ is the number of ways to make lunch from $n$ distinct ingredients, $f(z)=\sum \frac{a(n)}{n!} z^n$ is an exponential generating function. Then, say, $f^2$ is an exponential generating function for making two enumerated lunches from $n$ ingredients, $f^2/2$ for two not enumerated lunches, $f^3/3!$ for three non-enumerated lunches and so on. Totally $\exp(f)$ for arbitrary number of lunches. In our situation lunch is a cyclic ordering of ingredients when the number of ingredients divides $d$.

Answer (score 4):

For Q1, there is a quite nicely written 2014 [preprint by Cheda and Gupta.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.5477.pdf)